# Como hacer un código de barras 'interleaved2of5' en php

Tags: php

Me han encargado hacer unos códigos de barras del tipo: 'interleaved2of5' pero no se si es posible realizarlo con `php`.

He encontrado una clase `github`, pero creo que no es lo que necesito:

- [Enlace 1](https://github.com/waza-ari/barcodes/blob/master/src/tklovett/barcodes/symbologies/Interleaved2Of5.php)

Tambien he encontrado esta otra clase:

- [Enlace 2](https://github.com/fabioboris/php-interleaved-2-of-5/blob/master/I2of5.php)

Creo que esta ultima se parece mas a lo que estoy buscando. Pero no se como usarlo. Alguno de vosotros habeis generado algun código de barras de este tipo? Necesitaria que fuera en `php` porque luego tengo que generar un pdf y con javascript no funcionaria.

Tambien he encontrado información que hay un tipo de fuente, pero nose como añadirlo al pdf de la libreri `mPDF`.

[Enlace a la fuente](http://www.fontpalace.com/font-download/Interleaved+2of5/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usando la librería de https://github.com/waza-ari/barcodes

Instalar vía composer:

```
composer require wazaari/barcodes
```

Para generar un código de barras:

```
<?php
$generator = new BarcodeGenerator();
$barcode = $generator->generate(BarcodeType::INTERLEAVED_2_OF_5, "texto a codificar");

$svg  = $barcode->toSVG();
$html = $barcode->toHTML();
$png  = $barcode->toPNG();
```

Estos tres métodos aceptan de manera opcional 3 argumentos establecer ancho, alto y color, de la siguiente manera

```
$width = 50;
$height = 75;
$color = 'grey';

$svg  = $barcode->toSVG($width, $height, $color);
$html = $barcode->toHTML($width, $height, $color);
$png  = $barcode->toPNG($width, $height, $color);
```

El alto y ancho en píxeles, y el color cualquier nombre de color HTML válido.